# Convert column to date in R

Tags: r

Hi I have been trying to work out how to change a column to a date, I have almost given up and decided to do it in Excel but I want to learn how to do this in R.

```
Year
Jun 16, 2020
Jun 15, 2020
```

There is a comma in-between the day and year and I just want to be able to change it to DD-MM-YYYY format. Any help is welcome! :-)

Comment: How is the variable (column) stored now? Is it stored as character data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
library(lubridate)
lubridate::mdy("Jun 16, 2020")
```

If you then want it in your specific DD-MM-YYYY format, use this

```
yourdate <- lubridate::mdy("Jun 16, 2020")
format(yourdate, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Also, for completeness sake, here is the base R code:

```
as.POSIXct("Jun 16, 2020", format = "%b %d, %Y")
```

Comment: Worth noting that when you `format()` your date as `DD-MM-YYYY` it is no longer a `Date` class object, just a string. If you want to use it in R as a date, it's much better to keep it in the `Date` class (which prints as YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
as.Date(c("Jun 16, 2020", "Jun 15, 2020"), format = "%b %d, %Y")
#"2020-06-16" "2020-06-15"
```